# My iframe does not work with a UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iframe, uiwebview

I have tested my `iframe` everywhere and it works very well, but on `iOS` in `Objective-C`, it does not work on `UIWebView`, here is my code, can someone help me? Thanks

```
self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

NSString *Str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe frameborder=\"0\" width=\"359\" height=\"200\" src=\"//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/%@\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", identifier];

[_webView loadHTMLString:Str baseURL:nil];
```

My iframe :

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="359" height="200" src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x5b4cfz" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Your width is wider than an iPhone's width on some models, (I don't know if that's a real issue) and I'd recommend you use wkwebview not uiwebview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this Key to your info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

The main problem that I found is the base Url, was missing in your code, so add this code with base url `@"http://www.dailymotion.com"`, and changed the way to load html from `loadHTMLString` to `loadData` this always have better results for me

**Edited: Improved your code to handle width of WebView as @Mozahler suggest was wrong**

```
self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

NSString *identifierTest = @"x5b4cfz";

NSString *Str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe frameborder=\"0\" width=\"%@\" height=\"200\" src=\"//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/%@\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.webView.frame.size.width - 10], identifierTest];

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.webView.frame.size.width - 10]);

[_webView loadData:[Str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
          MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"
           baseURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.dailymotion.com"]];
```

it works, as you can see

[image]

Hope this helps