# Iframe not loaded on Safari - jQuery

Tags: jquery, ios, iframe, safari

I'm having problems with an iFrame loaded on Safari.

I have a simple iFrame that is loading a resource from behance.net. The iframe is working fine on every browser, except on Safari on both: macOS and iOS.

The weird thing is that if you try to hit refresh a couple of times, after a while it starts working, and it's showing the iframe, but after another while, if you keep hitting refresh, it stops again. Apparently it's having issues downloading a js file. Looking around, it seems that there might be a cache problem that regards only Safari, but I'm not completely sure.

Here you have an example: https://codepen.io/rolfo85/pen/JJMvwo

```
<iframe src="https://www.behance.net/gallery/52836321/Wild-Thing-T-shirt-design?iframe=1" scrolling="yes" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
```

Click on the link and if you see the iframe working, then clear the Safari cache and give it another try. It should theoretically stop working after you flushed the cache.

Have you guys any idea how to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44676297/my-iframe-does-not-work-with-a-uiwebview/44678933#44678933

Comment: thanks but I'm working with jQuery

Comment: ok!, good luck then!

Answer (score 3):

In my case adding a [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) for the domain the frame was from ( using  [frame-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src) ) allowed the frame to load:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
     content="frame-src https://docs.google.com;">
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because by default Safari does now allow Cross Domain Cookie to be written so if the iFrame src page requires some kind of session or cookie to be there for the page to load it will not load

[image]

So one way to test out if this is the issue for you as well. Is to copy the url of your iframe and open it in a separate tab and then reload your code pen in the previous tab and the content will now display as expected.

Here are some discussion about this on the [safari](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7232113?start=0&tstart=0) forum