# iframe doesnot loading in WKWebview

Tags: ios, swift, iframe, wkwebview

I used wkwebview to display web-content which contains a iframe inside it, but my static data display in it , but iframe  not showing . i have used loadHtmlstring method , since loadrequest not working in post method. i have added my code below , pls help

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = ["amount":"378.0","customer_id":"1000","reference_id":"123456","customer_email":"123.s@gmail.com","customer_mobile":"1111111","customer_name":"cust","address":"add"]

        let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
    Alamofire.request(Constant.sharedInstance().baseUrl+"online_payment"+Constant.sharedInstance().wsUrl, method:.post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in


            if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
                var urlRequest = URLRequest(url:URL(string: Constant.sharedInstance().baseUrl+"online_payment"+Constant.sharedInstance().wsUrl)! )


                urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
                self.webView.loadHTMLString(utf8Text, baseURL: nil)

                //self.webView.load(urlRequest)
            }
            else
            {
                let dic = ["message":"Something went wrong, Please try again"]



            }

    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44676297/my-iframe-does-not-work-with-a-uiwebview/44678933

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the answer. the problem with body only .

i will post my code below if any one needed later

```
{
    let urlAsString = Constant().baseUrl+"online_payment"+Constant().wsUrl
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")



           var parameters: [String: Any]? = nil


          if((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"userDetails")) != nil){
               let userDetail:NSDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userDetails") as! NSDictionary
            name = userDetail.value(forKey: "name") as? String
            mobile = userDetail.value(forKey: "phone") as? String
            customer_id = userDetail.value(forKey: "user_id") as? String
            email = userDetail.value(forKey: "email") as? String


         }
    if(reference_id == nil || reference_id == ""){
        if(appData.bookingDetailDic["reference_id"] == nil){
           reference_id = ""
        }
        else{
           reference_id =  appData.bookingDetailDic["reference_id"] as? String
        }


        date = appData.bookingDetailDic["selectDate"] as? String
        total = appData.bookingDetailDic["displayTotal"] as? String
        address = appData.bookingDetailDic["address"] as? String
    }else if(reference_id != nil){
        appData.bookingDetailDic["reference_id"] = reference_id
        appData.bookingDetailDic["displayTotal"] = total
        appData.bookingDetailDic["address"] = address
        appData.bookingDetailDic["selectDate"] = date

    }

                       parameters = ["amount":"\(String(describing: total!))","customer_id":"\(String(describing: customer_id!))","reference_id":"\(String(describing: reference_id!))","customer_email":"\(String(describing: email!))","customer_mobile":"\(String(describing: mobile!))","customer_name":"\(String(describing: name!))","address":"\(String(describing: address!))"]
    print(parameters as Any)

    do {

        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters as Any, options: [])
        request.httpBody = jsonData

    } catch
    {
        print("error writing JSON: \(error)")
    }

    webView.load(request as URLRequest)

}
```